# My game of life implementation

Tags: python, python-3.x, game-of-life, generator

I'm looking for comments on both the micro (individual lines of code) and macro (overall design) scale. My input/output format is a single string, with newlines delimiting rows and `'*'/' '` denoting alive and dead, respectively.

```
from itertools import product
from enum import Enum
class Direction(Enum): forwards = 1; backwards = 0

class State:
    table = {'*':True, ' ':False}

    def convert(self, grid, direction):
        if direction == Direction.forwards:
            table = self.table
        elif direction == Direction.backwards:
            table = {value:key for (key,value) in self.table.items()}
        else:
            raise ValueError("Invalid conversion direction!")

        return [[table[x] for x in row] for row in grid]

    def __init__(self, grid):
        grid = list(filter(None, grid.split('\n')))
        self.rows = len(grid); self.cols = len(grid[0])

        if not all(len(grid[i]) == self.cols for i in range(self.rows)):
            raise ValueError("Invalid game state!")

        self.grid = self.convert(grid, Direction.forwards)

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return self.grid[i]

    def __str__(self):
        return '\n'.join(map(lambda x: ''.join(x), self.convert(self.grid, Direction.backwards)))

def game(state):    
    ''' Takes a state in the input format and yields states in the output format. '''

    state = State(state)

    def alive(x,y):
        try:
            return state[x][y]
        except IndexError:
            return False

    while True:
        state.grid = [
            [2 <= sum(alive(xx,yy) for xx, yy in product([x-1,x+1], [y-1,y+1])) <= 3
             for (y,col) in enumerate(row)]
            for (x,row) in enumerate(state.grid)
        ]
        yield str(state)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding code style, it's better to respect the [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and use [Flake8](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flake8) to check your code.

For instance, replace:

```
from itertools import product
from enum import Enum
class Direction(Enum): forwards = 1; backwards = 0
```

by

```
from itertools import product
from enum import Enum


class Direction(Enum):
    forwards = 1
    backwards = 0
```

Regarding implementation:

When you raise an exception, always give the reason:

```
raise ValueError("Invalid conversion direction {0!r}! Only backwards or forwards.".format(direction))
```

In fact, `convert()` function could be “protected" because it is not used outside the class. And there is no need to check that the direction value is something else than backwards and forwards.

By convention, you could rename the `alive` function to `is_alive` because it is a predicate (it returns a Boolean). This function should be a method of `State` class because it use `state` variable.

For the same reason, the `game` function should also be a method. I don't like its name because we cannot understand that it's a generator. Something like `next_state` could be better.

At the end you calculate the `sum` of `alive()` values which are booleans. I consider this to be a bad practice: it's better to use 0 and 1.